# What is the proper way to use Nat/Natural in a singletons data type?

Tags: haskell, singleton-type

I am working on writing a prototype programming language in Haskell with polymorphic variants using the singletons library. I have a basic type of types that looks like this:

```
import Data.Singletons.TH
import Data.Singletons
import GHC.Natural
import Data.Singletons.TypeLits

$(singletons [d|
  data MyType = 
      PredT
    | ProcT [MyType]
    | IntT
    | FloatT
    | StringT
    | FuncT MyType MyType
    | VariantT Natural [MyType]
    | UnionT [MyType]
  |])
```

The `Natural` argument in `VariantT` is used to identity a particular variant, and it is important for this to actually be `Natural` (and not something like a Nat defined as an algebraic data type) for efficency reasons.

The issue is, with this definition, I get:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Natural’
     with actual type ‘Demote Natural’
```

Usually, in my experience with the singletons library, I get errors like this (to my understanding anyway), when trying to use a type as a singleton where `SingKind` is not supported for that type `e.x. for Char`, so I am at a loss as to why this is not working.

I have tried `Demote Natural`, `Nat`, as well as different imports (thinking maybe I'm not using the right "Nat" or "Natural" that singletons works with), all giving me similar errors. What's the issue here? Do I have to write the definitions that singletons generates manually for types for which `Demote a != a`, or is there something that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this is a still unfixed issue. If I understand correctly, currently the `singletons` TH script works by reusing the same type as both the promoted and demoted type, but `Nat` completely breaks this model. The long-term solution is to wait for GHC to merge `Nat` and `Natural`. Meanwhile, you will have to manually duplicate or generalize your type, or roll your own `Nat`.

https://github.com/goldfirere/singletons/issues/478

As a short-term fix, it seems possible to extend the TH script `singletons` to do something like that automatically. That would be a nice contribution for people who use singletons extensively.

Comment: That's a shame. I guess for now I will probably roll my own `Nat`, and wait until GHC 9.2 to get the preformance benefits of a builtin GHC Nat/Natural.